# jQuery load method to load next and previous pages asynchronously

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I'm creating a pagination that loads pages into a div using jQuery load method. I would like to add a next and previous button that would allow users to load either the next or previous page when clicked into div "#content". I've looked into jQuery .prev() and .next() methods but I don't know how I'd incorporate those methods here to achieve my goal. Any suggestions or demos highly welcome. Thank You in advance.

```
//References
var sections = $("a"),
   pageBody = $("#content"); //new/prev pages load in this div

//Manage click events
sections.on('click', function () {

   //load selected section
   switch (this.id) {
   case "page-1":
      pageBody.load("page1.html");
      break;
   case "page-2":
      pageBody.load("pagee2.html");
      break;
   case "page-3":
      pageBody.load("page3.html");
      break;
   case "page-4":
      pageBody.load("page4.html");
      break;
   case "page-5":
      pageBody.load("page5.html");
      break;
   default:
      break;
   }
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="content">

   <h2>Page TITLE</h2>
   <p>Page Text Goes Here</p>


   <div>
      <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="nav">
         <li>
            <a id="page-1" href="#"></a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a id="page-2" href="#"></a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a id="page-3" href="#"></a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a id="page-4" href="#"></a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a id="page-5" href="#"></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="next" href="#"></a>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can store current page in data attribute of next or prev link
ie. $('.prev').data('curPage', "page-1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the markup to

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>Page TITLE</h2>
    <p>Page Text Goes Here</p>

    <div> 
        <a class="prev" href="#"></a>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a id="page1" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a id="page2" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a id="page3" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a id="page4" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a id="page5" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul> 

        <a class="next" href="#"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

and use something like this

```
var sections = $(".nav a");

sections.on('click', function () {
    $("#content").load(this.id + '.html');
    sections.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.next').on('click', function() {
    var idx = sections.index( sections.filter('.active') ) + 1;
    idx = idx > sections.length-1 ? 0 : idx;
    sections.eq(idx).trigger('click');
});

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
    var idx = sections.index( sections.filter('.active') ) - 1;
    idx = idx < 0 ? sections.length-1 : idx;
    sections.eq(idx).trigger('click');
});
```

it increments the index and gets the next / previous element etc.

Comment: thats a nice way of doing things.

Comment: @dops - Thanks, seems more tidy to just do it like this. Haven't tested it (it's kinda hard to test with the ajax stuff), so not sure if it works, but the principle should at least work.

Comment: Thank you. The .active is removing and adding to sections but the pages are no longer loading into my #content div.

Comment: @user1584751 thats because your id is not the same as your filenames, remove the dashes from your id's (so page-1 becomes page1 and so on)

Comment: unfortunately this is still not working for me. In firebug I can see selected class next to the corresponding page ID, but this is when i click on the id="page" anchor's not the next or previous anchor buttons. I also notice that both the next and previous anchors show activity when i click on any id="page" anchor.

Comment: @user1584751 - I've made some small changes, but they shouldn't matter, I've also tested this extensively [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/aV8c9/), and I can see it's trying to load the different pages exactly the same as your original function did, so I can't really answer why it isn't working for you, as it should work just fine ?

Comment: Yup that should work, just concantenate the ID into the string to get whatever matches your files.

Comment: One final question. I have two images a gold star and a gray star to provide users with bread crumb to what page they're on. The current page should have a gold star and the others gray stars. I used an if else statement if($(this).className!='active') {$(this).children().attr('src','images/star_gold.gif')}else{$(this).children().attr('src','images/star_gray.gif');} the gold star is appearing but when i click another page the gold star remains on the previous page and also on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Give your #content div a data attribute and then use that as the current page e.g.

```
        <div id="content" data-nav="1">
            <h2>Page TITLE</h2>
            <p>Page Text Goes Here</p>
        <div>

            <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a data-nav="1" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a data-nav="2" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a data.nav="3" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a data.nav="4" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a data.nav="5" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="next" href="#"></a>
        </div>
```

Then your script can be something like this

```
//References
var sections = $("a"),
    pageBody = $("#content"),//new/prev pages load in this div
    prev = $(".prev"),
    next = $(".next");

//Manage click events
sections.on('click',changeSection(this.data('nav')));
prev.on('click',function() {
    // get the nav id
    navId = this.data('nav');
    prevId = navId - 1;

   //change the data
   changesection("page-" + prevId);
});


next.on('click',function() {
    // get the nav id
    navId = this.data('nav');
    prevId = navId + 1;

   //change the data
   changesection("page-" + prevId);
});

// You can place this function outside of the $(document).load 
function changeSection(id) {
 function(){
     // set the new nav
    pageBody.data('nav', id);
    //load selected section
    switch(id){
        case "1": 
                pageBody.load("page1.html");
                break;
        case "2": pageBody.load("pagee2.html");
                break;
        case "3": pageBody.load("page3.html");
                break;
        case "4": pageBody.load("page4.html");
                break;
        case "5": pageBody.load("page5.html");
                break;
        default:
                break;
    }
}
```

[You can check out more info on .data() here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

This is a quick thing I've done, there is definitely scope to make this better by refactoring the previous and next clicks and combining them into one function (by passing a true/false to add one or take one away) and you could potentially ditch the switch and load the page via a variable from the nav directly